# How to sort users in a view by the number of nodes authored of a specific node type?

Tags: 7, views

I was happy to find that in Views 3 I can sort users in a view by the number of nodes they have authored (Using a relationship "User: Content authored" and the Aggregation / 'Group by' - Count function, see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1735/3939)).

How can I do the same, but counting only nodes of a certain node type? (I'm actually using this in a view of profiles (Profile2), but using the relation "Profile: User UID" the solution would probably be the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correct, but have you tried setting up a normal filter:

Content: Type (= nodetype)

Comment: A normal content type filter was at first not possible since it is a profile view. But with the relationship "User: Content authored" a content type filter via the relation is indeed possible and it seems to work.